# Summing up in pandas based on Column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have a dataframe (df1) which looks like this:

```
Date                  Name          Category      #
01/01/01              Vegetables       A          15
01/01/01              Fruits           A          10
01/01/01              Meat             B          35
01/02/01              Vegetables       A           7
01/03/01              Vegetables       A           9
01/03/01              No Data         No Data    No Data
```

I want to create another dataframe (df2) that looks like this:

```
Date                  Classification          #
01/01/01              A                      25
01/01/01              B                      35
01/02/01              A                       7
01/03/01              A                       9
01/03/01             No Data                No Data
```

and another dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date                  Classification          #
01/01/01              A                      25
01/01/01              B                      35
01/02/01              A                       7
01/03/01              A                       9
```

which basically means classifying them by dates and category (df1) and the next dataframe (df2), classify by dates and category and excluding the "No Data"

I made this:

```
length = len(df2)

for i in range length:
    if df1 ['Category'] = "A":
        df1['Date'].map(df.groupby('Date')['Category].sum())
```

which doesn't give me anything as I believe this is still incomplete. Also, I have an error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert all the `#` values to numeric (coercing `No Data` to `NaN`), then groupby `Date` and `Category` before summing, filling `NaN` with `No Data` and the resetting the index:

```py
df2 = (pd
    .to_numeric(df1['#'], errors='coerce')
    .groupby([df1['Date'], df1['Category']])
    .sum(min_count=1)
    .fillna('No Data')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
       Date Category        #
0  01/01/01        A     25.0
1  01/01/01        B     35.0
2  01/02/01        A      7.0
3  01/03/01        A      9.0
4  01/03/01  No Data  No Data
```

Then you can just select `df3` as rows which don't have `No Data` in `Category`:

```
df3 = df2[df2['Category'] != 'No Data']
```

Output:

```
       Date Category     #
0  01/01/01        A  25.0
1  01/01/01        B  35.0
2  01/02/01        A   7.0
3  01/03/01        A   9.0
```

If you like, you can then revert `df3['#']` back to an integer:

```
df3.loc[:, '#'] = df3['#'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
       Date Category   #
0  01/01/01        A  25
1  01/01/01        B  35
2  01/02/01        A   7
3  01/03/01        A   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.drop(columns=['Name'], inplace=True) # you do not need this column for the grouping
df1['#'] = df1['#'].replace('No Data', 0) # To allow changing the column type to integer
df1['#'] = df1['#'].astype('int') # changing the column type to Integer
df2 = df1.groupby(['Date', 'Category']).sum() Grouping by
```

You can later reset the index:
df2 = df2.reset_index()

```
    Date    Category    #
0   01/01/01    A      25
1   01/01/01    B      35
2   01/02/01    A       7
3   01/03/01    A       9
4   01/03/01    No Data 0
```

Removing the 'No Data':

```
df2 = df2[df2['Category'] != 'No Data']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Category'], as_index=False)['#']
       .agg(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
            .fillna('No Data').sum()))
df2 = df1.where(df1.ne('No Data')).dropna()
```

Output:

```
(       Date Category        #
 0  01/01/01        A       25
 1  01/01/01        B       35
 2  01/02/01        A        7
 3  01/03/01        A        9
 4  01/03/01  No Data  No Data,
        Date Category   #
 0  01/01/01        A  25
 1  01/01/01        B  35
 2  01/02/01        A   7
 3  01/03/01        A   9)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code**

```
df2 = pd.to_numeric(df['#'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['#'])\
        .groupby([df['Date'], df['Category']]).sum()\
        .reset_index()\
        .rename(columns={'Category':'Classification'})
```

df2:

```
    Date        Classification  #
0   01/01/01    A               25.0
1   01/01/01    B               35.0
2   01/02/01    A               7.0
3   01/03/01    A               9.0
4   01/03/01    No Data         No Data
```

```
df2[df2['#'].ne('No Data')]
```

result:

```
    Date        Classification  #
0   01/01/01    A               25.0
1   01/01/01    B               35.0
2   01/02/01    A               7.0
3   01/03/01    A               9.0
```

I created `df2` because you wanted a DataFrame like `df2` as a result. It would be better not to create `df2`.

---

Code that produces the final result without creating `df2`.

```
df.loc[df['#'].ne('No Data'), '#']\
  .astype('int')\
  .groupby([df['Date'], df['Category']]).sum()\
  .reset_index().rename(columns={'Category':'Classification'})
```

output:

```
    Date        Classification  #
0   01/01/01    A               25
1   01/01/01    B               35
2   01/02/01    A               7
3   01/03/01    A               9
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date': ['01/01/01', '01/01/01', '01/01/01', '01/02/01', '01/03/01', '01/03/01'], 
         'Name': ['Vegetables', 'Fruits', 'Meat', 'Vegetables', 'Vegetables', 'No Data'], 
         'Category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'No Data'], 
         '#': ['15', '10', '35', '7', '9', 'No Data']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```